# How to get location as soon as FusedLocationApi connected?

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

I use the following codes to get the location of user using **FusedLocationApi** however it seems that onLocationChanged really works when the location is really changed but not sends the initial location. When I start the Api nothing happens but when I change my location the target function is called.

This is how I start the Api:

```
   @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
       LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
```

And this is how I call my own function:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        CurrentLocation=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+"_"+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        analyzeData(CurrentLocation);
    }
}
```

How can I get the location as soon as `onConnected` is fired not on location changes. Thanks

Comment: use setFastestInterval();
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26407873/7094064

Answer (score 0):

`onLocationChange` is called only When location is changed as you said above. 
So if you need to get location as soon as `onConnect` is fired you need to get it using the blew code as a work around till `onLocationChange` is fired

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    // Logic to handle location object
                }
            }
        });
```